# Fresh 20.04 install, ethernet won't connect

Tags: networking, ethernet

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 from USB to give it a shot but my ethernet connection won't connect.  Keeps popping up with a message of 'Activation of network connection failed'.  I've done some googling to try and troubleshoot so below is the output from some commands but I'm pretty much at a loss.  I had my phone usb tethered at the time so that might show up in outputs.

I've restarted my router just in case but ethernet connection was working literally right before I did install in Windows 10.

```
dmesg | grep e100
[    0.542912] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.542913] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.543018] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    0.629303] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    0.707914] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) ac:22:0b:c2:1c:18
[    0.707915] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    0.707952] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    0.708603] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    8.788473] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  325.609014] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[  330.549587] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  334.929073] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[  343.589396] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx


dmesg | grep eno1
[    0.708603] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    8.788473] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[    8.788512] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[  325.609014] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[  330.549587] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  334.929073] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[  343.589396] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  367.021050] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
[  373.069338] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx

sudo lshw -C network
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: ac:22:0b:c2:1c:18
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7239000-f7239fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:4
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 82:1f:50:46:1e:ec
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.166 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: Just an update that I was unable to resolve this without just doing a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu.  So not sure what occurred during the install but as far as I'm aware I chose no different options when reinstalling to get this working.